# Помогите сделать шапку адаптивной

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, header

Пытаюсь сделать шапку адаптивной ,но что-то идёт не так. Текст друг на друга наезжает .У `navbar-collaps` при сжатие и открывание панели меню цвет фона не устанавливается и т.д.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #b92b27, #1565c0)
}
.navbar {
  height: 60px !important;
  /* width: 100%; */
  /* display: table-column-group; */
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-brand{
  color: #63ADD0;

}.navbar-brand:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #63ADD0;
}
.nav-item {
  font-size: 22px;
  /* padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px; */
}

.searchbar {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #63add0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width:auto;

}

.search_input {
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: none;
  width: 0;
  caret-color: transparent;
  transition: width 0.4s linear; 
  margin-top:10px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.search_input {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.searchbar:hover > .search_input {
 
  width: 200px;
  caret-color: white;
  transition: width 0.4s linear;
}
.search_icon {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top:2px;
  /* margin-right: 6px; */
 /* align-items: center; */
}
.search_icon:hover{
  color: #6c757d;
}
@media (max-width: 1450px) { 
  .nav-item{
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;469;500;700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />

  <title>GameLand.by</title>
</head>

<div class="sticky-top">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 text-center ">
          <svg width="35px" height="35x" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-controller contriller mb-1 "
            fill="currentColor" style="color:#63ADD0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M11.119 2.693c.904.19 1.75.495 2.235.98.407.408.779 1.05 1.094 1.772.32.733.599 1.591.805 2.466.206.875.34 1.78.364 2.606.024.815-.059 1.602-.328 2.21a1.42 1.42 0 0 1-1.445.83c-.636-.067-1.115-.394-1.513-.773a11.307 11.307 0 0 1-.739-.809c-.126-.147-.25-.291-.368-.422-.728-.804-1.597-1.527-3.224-1.527-1.627 0-2.496.723-3.224 1.527-.119.131-.242.275-.368.422-.243.283-.494.576-.739.81-.398.378-.877.705-1.513.772a1.42 1.42 0 0 1-1.445-.83c-.27-.608-.352-1.395-.329-2.21.024-.826.16-1.73.365-2.606.206-.875.486-1.733.805-2.466.315-.722.687-1.364 1.094-1.772.486-.485 1.331-.79 2.235-.98.932-.196 2.03-.292 3.119-.292 1.089 0 2.187.096 3.119.292zm-6.032.979c-.877.185-1.469.443-1.733.708-.276.276-.587.783-.885 1.465a13.748 13.748 0 0 0-.748 2.295 12.351 12.351 0 0 0-.339 2.406c-.022.755.062 1.368.243 1.776a.42.42 0 0 0 .426.24c.327-.034.61-.199.929-.502.212-.202.4-.423.615-.674.133-.156.276-.323.44-.505C4.861 9.97 5.978 9.026 8 9.026s3.139.943 3.965 1.855c.164.182.307.35.44.505.214.25.403.472.615.674.318.303.601.468.929.503a.42.42 0 0 0 .426-.241c.18-.408.265-1.02.243-1.776a12.354 12.354 0 0 0-.339-2.406 13.753 13.753 0 0 0-.748-2.295c-.298-.682-.61-1.19-.885-1.465-.264-.265-.856-.523-1.733-.708-.85-.179-1.877-.27-2.913-.27-1.036 0-2.063.091-2.913.27z" />
            <path
              d="M11.5 6.026a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-1 1a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm2 0a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-1 1a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm-7-2.5h1v3h-1v-3z" />
            <path
              d="M3.5 6.526h3v1h-3v-1zM3.051 3.26a.5.5 0 0 1 .354-.613l1.932-.518a.5.5 0 0 1 .258.966l-1.932.518a.5.5 0 0 1-.612-.354zm9.976 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.353-.613l-1.932-.518a.5.5 0 1 0-.259.966l1.932.518a.5.5 0 0 0 .612-.354z" />
          </svg>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="main.html">
            <h4>GameLand</h4>
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9  text-center ">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav col-lg-6  ml-auto text-center">
              <li class="nav-item active mr-4 ml-4">
                <a class="nav-link" href="main.html">Главная</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-4 ml-4">
                <a class="nav-link " href="news.html">Новости</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-4 ml-4">
                <a class="nav-link " href="calendar.html">Календарь</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-4 ml-4">
                <a class="nav-link " href="contacts.html">Контакты</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav col-lg-6  mr-auto ">
              <li class="nav-item mr-1 ml-2">
                <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold "href="authentification.html">Вход</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item mr-1 ml-2">
                <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold "href="registration.html">Регистрация</a>
              </li>      
              <li class="nav-item mr-3 ml-3">
                <div class="container h-100">
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
                    <div class="searchbar">
                      <input class="search_input" type="text" name="" placeholder="Search...">
                      <a href="#" class="search_icon">
                          <svg width="25px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-search  search  mt-2 mr-2"
                            fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 0 1 1.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.415z" />

                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 1 1-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 13 0z" />
                          </svg>
                        </i>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
       

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можешь через @media  убрать margin с li. margin у тебя добавляется с помощью класса mr-4 и ml-4.
Цвет меню надо поменять в моб версии?